# Is there a way in WCF to have a pointer to a method on the server that it can use?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf

Suppose you have a method called "CalcArea()" in a WCF Contract. Once I get an instance of an object in a client I would like to let's say call myObject.CalcArea() and have it transmit that invoke request to the server object (that was used when I serialized my client object) and return the client the result. Is there a way to do this without creating a separate WCF service to "CalcArea()"? So something like this:

```
MyObject obj = Channel.GiveMeObject(name)
obj.ExecMethodOnServer()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand, so let me trace this out:

- You have a WCF service endpoint exposing a method CalcArea.
- You also have an instance of an object MyObject representing some geometric abstract, which also has a CalcArea() method.
- You want to calculate the area of this object using an instance method call, and have the data available on the client, but you want the heavy lifting of the area calculation (perhaps surface area calculation of a 3D model containing thousands of triangles) to be performed on the server.

Sure, you can do this. You need the CalcArea WCF OperationContract method to accept an object of the local type. As MyObject is apparently already a DataContract of this WCF service (evidenced by getting one from the GiveMeObject method), this is fairly trivial *as long as* MyObject instances have access to a WCF proxy:

```
public class MyObject()
{
    private MyWcfProxy WcfChannel;

    public MyObject (MyWcfProxy wcfChannel) {WcfChannel = wcfChannel;}

    public decimal CalcArea() { /*Area calculation logic*/ }

    public decimal CalcAreaOnServer() { return WcfChannel.CalcArea(this); }
}
```

You can also pass the connected WCF proxy object to CalcAreaOnServer on a call-by-call basis, allowing you to use a different instance of the proxy than the one from which you received this object instance (but requiring consuming code to be able to provide that proxy, possibly exposing implementation details best kept secret).

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for! Will try it out!